# ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, debian

During gitlab download on my PC(Ubuntu), "ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run" is waiting for a long time.

It continues when I run this command "systemctl restart gitlab-runsvdir.service " in a new terminal.

But the window does not load completely after logging into the Gitlab log in screen. Is this issue related to logrotation or could it be some other issue?

Answer (score 8):

I found that the `runsvdir-start` command (see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4257)) solved the problem.

Comment: sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start